# ui-sref nested state with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

```
.state('user-profile', {
        url: '/user-profile/:userId', //Parent state
        ...
.state('user-profile.profile',{ //nested
        url:'/profile', 
        ...
```

How can I access the url via `ui-sref` "user-profile/123/profile"

Currently I am trying this:

```
<a ui-sref="(user-profile({userId: currentUser._id})).profile">
```

This leads me to `user-profile/123`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, just use *state name* first, and then pass object `{}` with params:

```
//<a ui-sref="(user-profile({userId: currentUser._id})).profile">
<a ui-sref="user-profile.profile({userId: currentUser._id})">
```

Comment: Ah so simple! Thanks mate. Can I ask if there's any difference in the code you commented out and the uncommented code?

Comment: Also, I have seen people achieve the same using ng-click and $state.go to some state. Is it a bad practice or what?

Comment: And what if I have params in nested state as well. I would just have to pass another object after userId? I mean if I have /profile/:someId?

Comment: There is a working plunker, which should give you all the answers ;) also, ng-click could be used for dynamic stuff... but in general, if possible - ui-sref is preferred:  http://plnkr.co/edit/JuaUiJ3ySdtvl5VsbTAi?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so very much. Forgot to up its